# MDB new threads are calling onMessage while previous thread not finished

Tags: java, jboss, jms

In JBOSS EAP6 I've got a long running MDB thread listening to a JMS Queue. It received a Text Message with a DB key of work it should process (loop).

During its execution I noticed that new threads spawn new MDB instances, leading to inconsistencies. I do want to prevent that in a programmatic manner or in a configuration manner whithout changing performace. So, for instance check in the onMessage that work is ongoing. I can't change the DB Model.

Since I'm running in a single VM I'm on the verge (last resort) of using a static Set that stores the DB key. (I'm a bit under time pressure to fix this).

Comment: One idea might be using a singleton bean where I could aquire a lock for the DB Key in the message..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact I forgot the specify the transaction time-out. Hence the default time-out seems to kick in.

The problem was solved by adding the transaction time out:

```
 @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "transactionTimeout", propertyValue = "10800" )
```